# Is there a way to iterate over a list to add into the selenium code?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to iterate over a large list of dealership names and cities. I want to have it refer back to the list and loop over each entry and get the results separately.

```
#this is only a portion of the delers the rest are in a file
Dealers= ['Mossy Ford', 'Abel Chevrolet Pontiac Buick', 'Acura of Concord', 'Advantage Audi' ]

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\kevin\\Anaconda3\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get("https://www.bbb.org/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="findTypeaheadInput"]""").send_keys("Mossy Ford")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="nearTypeaheadInput"]""").send_keys("San Diego, CA")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/button""").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/a').click()
#contact_names= driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/ul[1]')
#print(contact_names)
#print("Query Link: ", driver.current_url)
#driver.quit()


    from selenium import webdriver
dealers= ['Mossy Ford', 'Abel Chevrolet Pontiac Buick', 'Acura of Concord']
cities = ['San Diego, CA', 'Rio Vista, CA', 'Concord, CA']
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\kevin\\Anaconda3\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get("https://www.bbb.org/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button").click()
for d in dealers:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="findTypeaheadInput"]""").send_keys("dealers")
for c in cities:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="nearTypeaheadInput"]""").send_keys("cities")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/button""").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/a').click()
contact_names= driver.find_elements_by_class_name('styles__UlUnstyled-sc-1fixvua-1 ehMHcp')
print(contact_names)
print("Query Link: ", driver.current_url)
driver.quit()
```

I want to be able to go to each of these different dealerships pages and pull all of their details then loop thru the rest. I am just struggling with the ideas of for loops within selenium.

Comment: Where is your loop! You yourself have the answer, you need to loop.

Comment: @MohamedAneesA I updated my code. I as said in my post I am just confused on how to for loop within selenium.

Answer (score -1):

Its better to create a dictionary with a mapping of dealer and city and loop through

```
Dealers_Cities_Dict =   {
     Dealers_Cities_Dict =  {
     "Mossy Ford": "San Diego, CA",
     "Abel Chevrolet Pontiac Buick": "City",
     "Acura of Concord'": "City",
     "Advantage Audi'": "City"
```

}

```
 for dealer,city in Dealers_Cities_Dict.items():
      //This is where the code sits
        driver.find_element_by_id("findTypeaheadInput").send_keys(dealer)
        driver.find_element_by_id("nearTypeaheadInput").send_keys(city)
```

Comment: There's no reason to create a dictionary when an array works just fine... is there? What problem does this solve?

Comment: @anant krish the issue I am having isnt adding them to a list where I am having a problem is finding a way to input the dealers and cities without to have them in the send.key as that would make the code gigantic.